# UEFI pxe boot Ghost for Windows 10 deployment

Tags: windows, disk-image, symantec

I need to use ghost cast server to image upcoming Win 10 machines. Unfortunately I have to use ghost for legacy reasons. Is it possible to network boot uEFI pxe computers and image GPT partitioned with the latest ghost cast server?

Answer (score 1):

Use Ghost v12.0.0.8019 (part of Symantec ghost solution suite 3.0, released July 2015) https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH111106.html
Ghost switch commands: https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH130961.html
Backup up Win10 GPT partitions using: ghost32 –fdsp –ib –split=660 –z9 –auto -NTEXACT